# Why there is no Toolbar(Action Bar) in android studio version 3.3

Tags: android-studio

Why there is no Toolbar(Action Bar) in android studio version 3.3

I have changed Gradle and also changed API 22 to API 28

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-JNrSaupDEHw/XD03ku6fwUI/AAAAAAAADVQ/MQac5h8R3YgA_rKclImPqJOdSI60prWPQCLcBGAs/s1600/android.png

why is version 3.2 available, but version 3.3 does not exist

Comment: You might have selected a theme with NoActionBar in your styles.xml. Provide the code of your styles.xml file

Comment: [link](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-xWmoWUmciGQ/XD1u5rS_h-I/AAAAAAAADVc/ceMKth0wKrIws_FrYiz1vMoBBgfCGrDIgCLcBGAs/s1600/andromeda.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

The solution is in tab design > click the eye icon > then checklist **Show Layout Decorations** in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` insead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as your parent theme in your styles.xml file. Then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in tab design > click the eye icon > then checklist Show Layout Decorations in the top left corner. I check and recommend